# setSelection on Gallery is resulting wrong item selected

Tags: android, onclick, gallery, adapter

I have set up a gallery for my app using `BaseAdapter`. Here is the code I used for the gallery.

```
homeGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.homeimggallery);
homeGallery.setSpacing(0);
homeGallery.setSelection(0);
homeGallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

private class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
     private int GalItemBg, temp;
     private Context cont;
     private View convertView1;
     private ViewGroup parent1;
     private Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.mask);
     private Bitmap whiteBorder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.stroke);
     private Bitmap blueBorder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.strokeactive);
     private Bitmap src;
     private Bitmap dest;
     private Canvas canvas;
     private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     private ImageView homeImgView;
     private ImageView[] homeImgViewArr= new ImageView[arrThumbImage.length];


     public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
       cont = c;
       TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(styleable.GalleryTheme);
       GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
       typArray.recycle();
       paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
     }
        public int getCount() {
            return arrThumbImage.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            homeImgView = new ImageView(cont);

            try{    

                src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), arrThumbImage[position]);

                dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                canvas = new Canvas(dest);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                canvas.save();
                canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() - src.getWidth())>> 1, (canvas.getHeight() - src.getHeight())>> 1);
                canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(dest, 0, 0, paint);

                homeImgView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(dest));            
                homeImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stroke);

                homeImgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                homeImgViewArr[position] = homeImgView;

            } catch(Exception e) {} 


            return homeImgView;
        }
    }
```

The gallery looks like below:

[image]

On finger movement, it is moving right to left or left to right as expected. Now I want to add some `onClick` action to items. If user click on any image, it will be selected and align in the middle. The following code is used for this action.

```
homeGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
homeGallery.setSelection(position);

                    }
                });
```

But it results wrongly. If I am selecting item no. 2, the item no. 3 got selected, although setSelection action is firing against item no 2. If I click on the right most item of the above pic, it is resulting line below:

[image]

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Did you know that index starts from 0 so if you are setting 2nd then in Gallery it will show you 3rd item as selected

Comment: Ya, I know that. All the position starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a Gallery myself, but I'm not quite sure what the problem is here, since your code is further than where I stand.

Anyways, since you click item 3?? and you get item 4 centered I can think of a few options:

-Something is wrong with the array indexes, might wanna take a log of the positions.

-Personally, I work with an array of Integer and on the getView() I just get the position which is easier than what you're doing I believe.

public ArrayList mImageIds = new ArrayList(); the array...
i.setImageResource(mImageIds.get(position)); and in getView() it's sorted.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I have done the same thing, but image need some modification, so I used masking for the modification.